# UI Interface on Paper53?

Tags: patent-infringement, user-interface

Is the UI interface on Paper53 patented? Specifically, the screen with the open book where you flip between the pages.

Comment: At Ask Patents on-topic questions are either questions about how the U.S. patent system works or requests for help locating prior to be used against a U.S. patent or patent application.

Comment: Edited to reflect that